# How can I check if a memory leak exists the dbexpress components?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, dbexpress, delphi-10-seattle

In a very simple expample VCL project (1 form, 1 grid, 1 simpledataset) I'm requesting data from a random table from a Micorosft SQL Server using dbexpress `Data.DBXMSSQL`. I've enabled memory leak reporting with `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;` and as long as only reading data and doing local edits, no memory leaks are reported. If I post changes to the server using

```
  SimpleDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
```

I get the following message after the program has terminated:

[image: memory leak]

If I **enable** *FastMM4* *FullDebugmode*, no memory leak is reported. Is there a bug in the memory leak reaporting by delphi 10 or is there a memory leak I have to worry about?

Example unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, SimpleDS,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Data.SqlExpr, Data.DBXMSSQL;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    SimpleDataSet1: TSimpleDataSet;
    procedure SimpleDataSet1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.SimpleDataSet1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  SimpleDataSet1.ApplyUpdates(0);
end;
```

Form definition (simplified):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    DataSource = DataSource1
  end
  object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
    ConnectionName = 'XXXXXXXX'
    DriverName = 'MSSQL'
    LoadParamsOnConnect = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Params.Strings = (
      'BlobSize=-1'
      'DataBase=XXXXXXXX'
      'DriverName=MSSQL'
      'ErrorResourceFile='
      'HostName=XXXXXXXX'
      'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
      'LocaleCode=0000'
      'OS Authentication=False'
      'Password=XXXXXXXX'
      'Prepare SQL=False'
      'SchemaOverride=%.dbo'
      'User_Name=XXXXXXXX')
    Connected = True
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = SimpleDataSet1
  end
  object SimpleDataSet1: TSimpleDataSet
    Active = True
    Aggregates = <>
    Connection = SQLConnection1
    DataSet.CommandText = 'SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXX'
    DataSet.MaxBlobSize = -1
    DataSet.Params = <>
    Params = <>
    AfterPost = SimpleDataSet1AfterPost
  end
end
```

Comment: Leak reporting is solid in my experience. I would trust it.

Comment: Use FastMM with the debugmode DLL and check the stack trace to get more insight.

Comment: @whosrdaddy What do you mean by "with the debugmode DLL"? As I wrote, I already enabled Fastmm with Full debug mode and no memory leaks are reported anymore. Are you referring to a specific setting in the FastMM4 options?

Comment: Sorry missed that detail. What I meant to ask is, did you enable the logfile?

Comment: @whosrdaddy `{$define LogErrorsToFile}` was enabled...

Comment: did you try not to use fastmm at all and instead use ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true property ? Fastmm4 is a bit outdated.

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy The above screenshot is generated with `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true`. But I think this is not enough information how to prevent the leak.